# Contract Event Filter returning empty array when using get_all_entries Web3.py

Tags: web3.py, python

Python Version: 3.9.6

Web3.py Version: 5.21.0

Used Geth and Infura (HTTPS and Web Sockets)

Tested on Ethereum Mainnet and Kovan

I have tried this before about a month ago with the exact same code and it worked as intended. However, for some reason it is returning an empty array.

```
from web3.auto import w3
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_factory, abi=uniswap_factory_abi)
event_filter = contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
print(event_filter.get_all_entries())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the filter to return the events in the latest block.

Likely, there are zero events in the latest block.

Try a random block number in the past instead.